# Regex replace matches

Tags: python, regex

Assuming I have this entry in a dictionary:

```
'Michaele Frendu': ['Micheli Frendu', 'Michael', 'Michaele']
```

which means that for every instance of the value in the list, it has to be replaced by the key.

ie:

if I have this sample input:

```
s = 'concessit et assignavit Micheli Frendu presenti viridarium'
```

this would be replaced by:

```
s = 'concessit et assignavit Michaele Frendu presenti viridarium'
```

The problem is when I already have a Michaele Frendu in my text and Michaele is also an item in the list ex:

```
s = 'Pro Michaele Frendu contra Lucam Zamit'
```

This is changing to:

```
s = 'Pro Michaele Frendu Frendu contra Lucam Zamit'
```

where my desired output is:

```
s = 'Pro Michaele Frendu contra Lucam Zamit'
```

In this case I don't want any replacement as the value is already equal to the key.

I am using this regex pattern but is not working:

```
my_regex = r"\b(?=\w)" + re.escape(l) + r"\b(?!\w)"
s = re.sub(my_regex, k, s)
```

where k is the key and l is a value from the list

Comment: What about a mere postprocess like `.replace('Frendu Frendu', 'Frendu')`? How do you build the pattern and run replacements? Can you modify the dictionary values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply place the replacement in the first of your regex alternation list, so that it will replace the replacement with itself, with higher precedence than the alternative keywords:

```
import re
d = {'Michaele Frendu': ['Micheli Frendu', 'Michael', 'Michaele']}
s = 'Pro Michaele Frendu contra Lucam Zamit'
for k, v in d.items():
    print(re.sub('|'.join(map(re.escape, (k, *v))), k, s))
```

This outputs:

```
Pro Michaele Frendu contra Lucam Zamit
```

And with `s = 'concessit et assignavit Micheli Frendu presenti viridarium'`, this outputs:

```
concessit et assignavit Michaele Frendu presenti viridarium
```

For clarity, note that `'|'.join(map(re.escape, (k, *v)))` returns the following during the iteration:

```
Michaele\ Frendu|Micheli\ Frendu|Michael|Michaele
```